# How can I access this variable inside my function, so I can output it into my ejs file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output this function into my ejs file. But I don't know how to access the output variable?

```
function ejsoutput(json){
  var output = json;
};

app.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', { leaderboard: output });  
});
```

Comment: with that little snippet of code its pretty hard to tell what you are trying to do. You have declared/defined a function but are not using it and it also doesnt do anything or return a value. Do you possibly have the function defined elsewhere and are really just trying to use it here? You should go and do some reading on how to declare a function and how to call a function

Comment: Yes I am calling the function in this promise - .then(response => response.json())
.then(json => ejsoutput(json))
}

Comment: I'm just trying to output the data from my promise into my ejs file so I can veiw it on the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. It might work,

```js
var output = null;
function ejsoutput(json){
  output = json;
};

app.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
    res.render('index', { leaderboard: output });  
});
```

Comment: In HTML page, use it like this `JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);`